# How to customize Spring JWT authentication to log out failures

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

I use Spring Security to handle authentication. There I want to log out (logging not log in/out) specific details of specific JWT authentication failures. Those details are either in the request (remote address, endpoint) or in the token itself (custom claims). The failures I want to catch are invalid signature, invalid audience and the default stuff (timestamp and issuer).

What I tried so far:

1. Using an implementation of HandlerInterceptor. The problem with that, if the token is invalid before, the request will not be prehandled here.
2. I tried to use custom validators `oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(this::createCustomJwtValidator)` while this works well for all other token claims, I found no way to detect an invalid signature.
3. then I tried to use an authenticationEntryPoint along with my custom validators as in:

```
  private void oauthCustomizer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> oauth2ResourceServer) {
 oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(this::createCustomJwtValidator).authenticationEntryPoint(logJwtAuthenticationFailure());
  }

  private AuthenticationEntryPoint logJwtAuthenticationFailure() {
    return (request, response, exception) -> {
      if(exception.getMessage().contains("signature")) {
        logUnauthorizedAccess(request, exception.getMessage());
      }
      BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint delegate = new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint();
      delegate.commence(request, response, exception);
    };
  }
```

The problem with that: Both my validators and the entryPoint catch and log out the failure, so I get doubled logs, with the difference, that logUnauthorizedAccess has no access to the token claims and I can't log them out. That's why I added the check for "signature" up there to log only Invalid Signature (but it also misses important information, which is no problem).

So what is my goal:

1. Either detect an invalid signature in a validator or decoder.
2. Or have access to token claims here in the entry point.